# Is the Minecraft Java edition still available for Windows 10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I purchased the Java edition 6 years ago, but after some time I uninstalled it. A few weeks ago I wanted to play again. When I went to download it, I got a message that I have a free code for the Windows 10 edition, so I downloaded that edition, but I didn't like it (among other things, you couldn't press F3 to view your coordinates). Today I wanted to download the Java version again, but it seems I cannot; when I go to "Download", it says "You already own Minecraft" and I have an option to download it on Windows 10. Whatever I try, I always seem to end up with that message.

Is it still possible to play the Java edition on Windows 10?

Comment: The missing debug screen is a weird reason to dislike MCPE. There's an enforced chat filter, redstone randomness, no NBT in commands, it's closed source (or at least a lot harder to decompile), there's no version for Linux and Mac, no 1.13 commands, no offhand, updates are regularly rushed and therefore much worse than the previous version, the development is focused on little children even more than regular Minecraft and in general you can notice the strong influence of Microsoft. Those are 10 good reasons to hate MCPE. The missing debug screen is just a minor thing, maybe in 100th place.

Comment: @FabianRöling Haha I guess that's true. I only played it for an hour so I didn't have time to notice any redstone randomness, but I do remember not having an offhand which was annoying. Also you couldn't customize the world to make it (for example) large biomes. Most of the other stuff you said is not that annoying for me I guess because I am a basic player. However, like you say, I did see the hand of Microsoft in it.

Comment: @FabianRöling and Ovi, you people must not have updated the game in forever. Bedrock Edition has grown alot. They are starting to integrate Data Tags, and you can hold plenty of items in your offhand. No shields, but... I haven't gotten around to play with redstone, however.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can download the Java edition on [the Minecraft website](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download).